# iOS swift prepareForSegue cannot pass data between two viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code of two viewcontroller, need pass "numberToDisplay" from class bookTwo to class bookThree, but it not work, always show 0 in bookThree.
I am using swift3 on ios 10, xocod 8.
bookTwo:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
class bookTwo: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ms1"{
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? bookThree;
        destinationVC?.numberToDisplay = 7

    }
  }
}
```

bookThree

```
import UIKit

class bookThree: UIViewController {
var numberToDisplay = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var showType: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  showType.text = "Tapped \(numberToDisplay) times."
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: it should work fine

Comment: Try changing `var numberToDisplay = 0` to `var numberToDisplay: Int!`

Comment: Please check my answer and reply..

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, the signature for method "prepareForSegue" has changed. So replace the code for "prepareForSegue" with this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ms1"{
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as? bookThree
            destinationVC?.numberToDisplay = 7

        }
    }
```