# how to take a saved string and use it another view controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift3, nsuserdefaults

The text below here uses a uitextield and saves it to a label. Lets say this is view controller A.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var labelz: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


   @IBAction func ritaOra(_ sender: Any) {
    labelz.text = text.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(labelz.text, forKey: "myName")
    text.text = ""

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myName") as? String
{
    labelz.text = x

    }
}
```

This code below is what I use in a camera. Lets say this is view controller b.

```
let text = "Python"
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 125, y: 400, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300))
 label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 122)

 label.textColor = UIColor.blue
 label.alpha = 0.3
 label.text = text
```

How can I take the textview in view controller a and place into where let text = "Python" (in view controller b) is currently.

Answer (score 0):

How are you navigating from ViewController A -> B?

If you're using a Storyboard Segue, you'll want to look into [`prepareForSegue()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue). It is called when a segue is started, and gives you a place to set variables on the ViewController you are segueing to (referred to as the destination). Inside `prepareForSegue` you would simply set the variable on the destination ViewController.

See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40394037/1575489

Comment: I was navigating using a simple next page button.